# Can we play .swf file in webview

Tags: android, android-webview, flash, android-mediaplayer

Can we play .swf file in webview?
It works with 4.0 and lower version. But unable to play in higher version.
Is there any way to play .swf file?

Answer (score 0):

so far i come to know that we can play `swf`  on `4.0+` using Firefox. You just need to download

- [Mozilla Firefox for android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox&hl=en&rdid=org.mozilla.firefox)
- [Adobe Flash Player 11](http://www.pcnexus.net/2014/01/how-to-install-flash-player-on-galaxy-tab-pro-101-sm-t525.html)

Now go to Firefox Settings/Customize/Display/Plugins and choose enabled.Start Flash Player and choose Firefox as default browser. Enter your flash file url in browser.

And if we want to make it work in app we have to use `GeckoView` [link](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView)